Why does CountA give me more results than using FILTER with either NOT(ISBLANK or <>""
If i do countA on a columnA of sheet1 it says 899 results.
If on  sheet2 I do either of
=FILTER('sheet1'!A6:A5826,'sheet1'!A6:A5826<>"")
or
=FILTER('sheet1'!A6:A5826,(NOT(ISBLANK('sheet1'!A6:A5826))))
then i only get 876 rows. wny?
countA is correct because when I copy my original column A from sheet1 and paste it next to the result of the two FILTERED columns in sheet2 I can see an additional 23 rows.
and if i  sort these columns so i can identify the problem cells, I find relatively innocuous cells with text strings in the original data, results which are completely missing in my two FILTERED attempts.
Rather than trying to understand the wizardry behind this outcome, can anyone offer me a more watertight way to do the FILTER so that I get 899 results? I have tried various gleanings from the web but not found something that works eg
=SUMPRODUCT(–(LEN(bj6:bj5826)>0)) which i stumbled upon somewhere.
Appreciate any (simple-ish) suggestions

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

When you do:
=FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"")

or
=FILTER(A:A,LEN(A:A))

The formula filters out both empty cells and cells that contain an empty string "", so the empty strings are not taken into account.
But when you do:
=FILTER(A:A,NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)))

The formula only filters out the cells that are actually empty leaving the cells that contain the empty string "".
Since the COUNTA function also counts empty strings "", these two formulas are equivalent:
=COUNTA(A:A)
=ROWS(FILTER(A:A,NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))))

While these two aren't:
=COUNTA(A:A)
=ROWS(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""))

This is why returning an empty string is considered bad practice, and it’s always better to avoid it.
❌ IF(condition,"",do_something)
✅ IF(condition,,do_something)
❌ IFERROR(formula,"")
✅ IFERROR(formula)


Thanks for taking the time to respond. What is odd, in my example, is that the values which countA counts, and which FILTER('sheet1'!A6:A5826,'sheet1'!A6:A5826<>"") misses out include "After hours palliative care organisation ...." for example. "C1545  - John Doe is carer" is another example. In other words, countA counts those values, as expected, but FILTER with <>"" does not include them in the filtered list. Appreciate any other thoughts you might have. and thanks for explaining that it is better to not use <>""

could you share a sample sheet where you reproduce the issue? You can Make an anonymous sample document

PLEASE IGNORE ABOVE COMMENT: Thanks for taking the time to respond. It wasn't an issue of empty strings messing my results it turns out. I now am getting the same results for <> and LEN and NOT ISBLANK - but i take your advice about avoiding the latter if there might be empty strings involved

turns out I was missing some rows in my FILTER compared to what I had in my countA. sheesh.
